# pypy pip: error when attempting to install cryptography on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: python, pip, pypy

When installing cryptography the wheel fails to build and pip outputs the following error code:

```
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:12:12: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
#  include <pyconfig.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Previous instances of this problem suggest that this is an issue with Python headers and recommend installing `build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev`
However these packages are already installed on my system. All the dev packages are there; no packages suggested from previous, already answered issues are missing

Where's the issue then?

Comment: The suggested duplicate is 4th in Google on _pip "pyconfig.h: No such file or directory"_.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev already followed those steps. thus the new question.

Comment: Well, you need to get the headers for your `pypy` somehow and make the compiler see them. How depends on how you got your `pypy` (I checked that the headers come with the download on the official site) and how you're compiling the extension -- [which you didn't provide the details for](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The Python library development files need to be installed to compile extensions from source. Do you have `libpython-dev` installed ?

```
apt-get install libpython-dev
```

Comment: yes, as I said in my question. All dev files have already been installed

Comment: You said 'build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev' that is different to libpython-dev